# How to sort json in the dump statement?

Tags: python, json, sorting, date, dump

I read this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_json_sort.asp) at W3Schools, and noticed it showed you can dump and sort by alphabetical order, is it possible to sort by the time?

My dump statement:

```
with open("./warns.json","w") as f:
  json.dump(warns,f)
```

How would I dump it and sort it by date?

Comment: `json.dump(warns, f, sort_keys=True)`?

Comment: You can sort only keys of dictionary (object/mapping) by using `json.dumps(warns, f, sort_keys = True)`. List (array) can not be sorted by this function. I.e. `{"b": 456, "a": 123}` will be sorted to `{"a": 123, "b": 456}`, but `[3, 2, 1]` will remain `[3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @deadshot doesnt that only sort alphabetically, and Arty im not sure what you mean??

Comment: @RomulusHill I updated my comment above with extra example.

Comment: Oh I understand now arty

Comment: @RomulusHill In other words `{}` (dictionary) structure will be sorted but `[]` (array) will remain same.

Comment: @RomulusHill Can you `print(warns)` to console? And show us some of output. So that we can see how `warns` structure is organized.

Comment: Thanks to @Arty the issue is resolved, I didnt realise im storing values in a string and somehow I expected json to shuffle them around into the correct date order, silly me! So dont worry this is resolved!

Comment: If your `print(warns)` to console and show us part of output we can help you to solve your task. Maybe `sort_keys = True` will not solve your problem, but some other pythonic code may do what you need.

Comment: Also if you store your structure `warns` as dictionary with string keys equal to time/date, then `sort_keys = True` will solve your task, e.g. if you have `{"2021-01-22 10:15": [1, 2, 3], "2021-01-22 08:07": [4, 5, 6]}` then using sort_keys will sort this structure to `{"2021-01-22 08:07": [4, 5, 6], "2021-01-22 10:15": [1, 2, 3]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump :

> If sort_keys is true (default: False), then the output of dictionaries will be sorted by key.

Sorting by date is different, as it depends on the structure of your JSON. If you really need it, you can modify the encoder:

> To use a custom JSONEncoder subclass (e.g. one that overrides the default() method to serialize additional types), specify it with the cls kwarg; otherwise JSONEncoder is used.

This is used to serialize types, but you may be able to also control the output order.

Another solution is to use a sorted array in the JSON, to ensure the order is respected.